# How to display multiple tables based on value

Tags: php, mysql, html-table, echo

I have an inventory page that displays my information, I'm attempting to have multiple tables that are based on department value, basically I want to display each department in tables by themselves rather than a single table, seems like it would make the page easier to view, yes I'm a new, yes I'm using mysql, I know its deprecated blah blah blah, this is a local db and I'm self-taught. Do I have to use some kind of loop or is there an easier way?

```
<?php
   $connect = mysql_connect("localhost", "Me", "password") or die ("Check your connection.");
   mysql_select_db("radio");
   $quey1="select * from inventory order by department, user";
   $result=mysql_query($quey1) or die(mysql_error());
?>
<table border=1 cellpadding="10 cellspacing="1 style="background-color:#F0F8FF;" >
 <tr>
  <th>Serial Number</th>
  <th>Model</th>
  <th>Department</th>
  <th>User</th>
  <th>Date</th>
 </tr>
<?php
   while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
      echo "<tr><td>";
      echo $row['serialnumber'];
      echo "</td><td>";
      echo $row['model'];
      echo "</td><td>";
      echo $row['department'];
      echo "</td><td>";
      echo $row['user'];
      echo "</td><td>";
      echo $row['date'];
      echo "</td></tr>";
   }
   echo "</table>";
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    <?php
   $connect = mysql_connect("localhost", "Me", "password") or die ("Check your connection.");
   mysql_select_db("radio");
   $quey1="select * from inventory order by department, user";
   $result=mysql_query($quey1) or die(mysql_error());
   while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
      $resultsArr[] = $row;
      $departments[] = $row['department'];
   }


foreach($departments as $department) { ?>
  <table border=1 cellpadding="10 cellspacing="1 style="background-color:#F0F8FF;" >
     <tr>
        <th>Serial Number</th>
        <th>Model</th>
        <th>Department</th>
        <th>User</th>
        <th>Date</th>
     </tr>
   <?php foreach($resultArr as $value) 
        if($value['department'] == $department) { ?>
           <tr>
                <td><?php echo $value['serialnumber']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['model']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['department']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['user']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['date']; ?></td>
           </tr>
   <?php } ?>
<?php } ?>
```

Try this out and tell me if it worked.

Romeo Onisim

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Romeo, I'm getting Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' on line 9, but I'm headed in the right direction. David I'm not sure what you mean, how would this problem not have occurred? I have it displaying every record on one page as it should, I'm merely attempting to break up the table into multiple to make it easier to view.

Comment: Add ; after : $departments[] = $row['department']

Answer (score 0):

You could just create the whole table inside the loop. Then check when a new department value comes and then close the previous table and open a new one.

Just so you know having this mixed logic creates complexity when there doesn't need to be. If you think of moving all your DB interactions to one part, dealing with the result of the DB query in another, outputting the result in another, you'll find that this problem wouldn't even have occurred. This is a very basic MVC concept.